Filter JSON array by property and return all details associated with that property in steps
I have a JSON array that I would like to filter in stages. An example of the array is as follows
[
    {
        "env": "ENG",
        "details": [
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "TestA",
                "programs": [
                    {
                        "name": "TestA",
                        "type": "AA"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tenantId": 5,
                "tenantName": "Demo",
                "programs": [
                    {
                        "name": "DEMO",
                        "type": "BB"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DEMO2",
                        "type": "BB"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "env": "Span",
        "details": [
            {
                "tenantId": 4,
                "tenantName": "Cat",
                "programs": [
                    {
                        "name": "CAT",
                        "type": "123"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tenantId": 5,
                "tenantName": "Demo",
                "programs": [
                    {
                        "name": "DEMOSpan",
                        "type": "www"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DEMOU2",
                        "type": "eee"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]

For the first stage I would like to filter the array by first the top level, this is env in the example so say ENG so it returns this:
 {
        "env": "ENG",
        "details": [
            {
                "Id": 3,
                "Name": "TestA",
                "programs": [
                    {
                        "name": "TestA",
                        "type": "AA"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tenantId": 5,
                "tenantName": "Demo",
                "programs": [
                    {
                        "name": "DEMO",
                        "type": "BB"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "DEMO2",
                        "type": "BB"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

Finally would like to filter the resulting array by either Id or Name so say if I chose filter by Name=TestA. The result I am looking for is the entire single array as follows:
       {
            "Id": 3,
            "Name": "TestA",
            "programs": [
                {
                    "name": "TestA",
                    "type": "AA"
                }
            ]
        }

What would be the best way to go about this in C#?
TIA

This reminds me of XPath with XML and there's a library to do stuff like var token = jsonObject.SelectToken("$.store.book[0].title"); with Json called JsonPath, it comes with Newtonsofts implementation. System.Text.Json doesn't support the selectToken instead its done by traversing Documents and Elements.

@JeremyThompson - I'm a recent convert to System.Text.Json, it's wild it still doesn't support JsonPath

Example of one way using System.Text.Json and LINQ:
var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonArray>(json) ?? throw new JsonException("Unable to deserialize JSON.");
var bar = foo.Where(n => n?["env"]?.GetValue<string>() == "ENG");
var baz = bar?.SelectMany(n => n?["details"]?.AsArray() ?? [])
              .Where(n => n?["Name"]?.GetValue<string>() == "TestA");

